# iphone X browser freeze during input text

Tags: html

i have a issue, when typing data in a html form in iphone X IOS 14.2 in safari
the page freeze for some seconds
any idea about the issue
the website in question is https://louvine.foxorders.com/ (menu s'inscrire)

Comment: in other device android, and also in iphone 6s all is OK, only on iphone X

Comment: Is this problem only on one iphone X device, or on many iphone X?

Comment: on many iphone X

Comment: given the massive nature of this problem, I think the reason is not in your site .. so I found a couple of material on this topic. maybe you will be interested - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252067705

Comment: and this is for elimination on the user side - https://appletoolbox.com/ios-safari-freezes-fix/

Comment: when i enter to the website louvine.foxorders.com from my iphone X, in menu s'inscrire, when a start to fill form inscription,  when a try to fill password or address, the page freeze for some seconds

Comment: and then it returns to normal?

Comment: yes it return to. the normal